# Accessibility VoiceOver on custom view like on collection view

Tags: ios, uikit, accessibility, voiceover

At the moment I'm working on custom view.

I need to achieve the behavior of the VoiceOver as in the standard UICollectioView. Where when I translated the focus from an element that is outside the hierarchy of my custom view to the one that in the hierarchy, VoitserOver reads a accessibilityLabel of custom view and then accessibilityLabel of selected view

```
@interface FBMinimizedPlayerControlPanelView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) ImageView *artworkView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *subtitleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ImageContainer *togglePlayPauseButton;

@end

@implementation FBMinimizedPlayerControlPanelView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setUp];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setUp {

//    self.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    self.accessibilityLabel = @"Miniplayer.";
    self.accessibilityHint = @"Double tap to expand the miniplayer.";
//    self.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES;

//set up code 

    [self.togglePlayPauseButton configureWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Play" forState:BEToggleButtonStateSelected];
    [self.togglePlayPauseButton configureWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Pause" forState:BEToggleButtonStateNormal];

}

- (nullable NSArray *)accessibilityElements {


    return @[self.togglePlayPauseButton];
}

@end
```

And now when I turn VoiceOver It read only pause/play button, but I want that the behavior was as in the UICollectionView, where in the beginning reads accessibilityLabel of the collectionView and then the item  accessibilityLabel.

For Example:
collectionView accessibilityLabel: "collectionView",
cell's content label accessibilityLabel: "cell's content label",

In situation that I describe above VoiceOver red it like : "collectionView, cell's content label" (only when previous focused wasn't a subview from collectionView);

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To be well analyzed by VoiceOver, a collection view may be seen as an array that should be traversed once defined with the `adjustable` trait.

Each element of the collection view must then be defined as a `UIAccessibilityElement`.

To understand how that should be implemented, I suggest you take a look at the `WWDC 2018 - Deliver an exceptional accessibility experience` video whose content is perfectly summarized [here](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18230.html) and whose presented example can be [downloaded](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/delivering_an_exceptional_accessibility_experience).